# Linear algebra, matrix in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

, Can you help me with the following exercise?

Show that doesn't exists matrix $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $$AB-BA=I$$

Has something to do with the annihilator?
Thanks !

Comment: Every commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$ has trace $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Had there been such matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB-BA=I_n$, then taking trace on both sides we will have $trace(AB-BA)=n$. But we already know that trace$(AB)$= trace($BA)$. So we will get $0=n$, which is not possible.